# Как в kohana сделать подобную ссылку site.com/nameuser

Tags: kohana

где nameuser это имя пользователя.

Comment: Чтобы у вас был хоть какой-то ответ: [Kohana 3.3 Routing](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing)

Answer (score 1):

В конец bootstrap.php добавляешь

```
Route::set( 'users', '(<username>)',array('username' => '.+'))->defaults(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Именно в конец или ближе к концу - т.к. этот роут будет срабатывать на все урлы.

в Controller_Users  username получать так:

```
$username = Request::current()->param('username', '');
```

Но тут важный момент, т.к. все урлы будут попадать сюда - тут тебе обязательно надо обработать 404 ошибку.